# Wordpress and Bootstrap: Dropdown menu does not works

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing this [website](http://birsmatt.ch/de/wohnungen/) and a you can see i'm using Wordpress and Bootstrap.

I'm trying to add a `<button>` element with a dropdown menu inside. I just created it with this code

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

...but does not work. What I'm doing wrong?

Any tips?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the boostrap JS as inclusion in your website